# Wikipedia movie table to XML

Tags: xml, wikipedia, wikitext

How to convert a Wikipedia table to a XML file? I tried importing with Google Docs, but all formatting is lost completely and restoring it is a tedious work.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2013

```
<movie>
    <table_no._21>
        <title>Table No. 21</title>
        <genre>Thriller/Drama</genre>
        <director>Aditya Daat</director>
        <cast>Paresh Rawal, Rajeev Khandelwal, Tena Desae</cast>
        <cbfc>A</cbfc>
    </table_no._21>
</movie>
```

Comment: Why don't you save the HTML source for that table and do an XSLT transform to XML? Or look for a movie database where you can extract the information in XML

Comment: @AdolfoPerez thanks for the information :) I copied the html table and extracted and converted as Excel and then to XML with Outwit Hub! Easiest Way

Answer (score 0):

Adolfo's answer: Why don't you save the HTML source for that table and do an XSLT transform to XML? Or look for a movie database where you can extract the information in XML.